# Bit Strings: checking if one bitstring is a subset of another

Tags: java, algorithm, arrays, byte

I am representing the set of english alphabets as a 26 bit bitstring. The first bit corresponds to 'a', the set bit to 'b', and so on.
Thus,
The string ab is represented as 11000000000000000000000000
Now, given two bit strings, I want to check if bitstring 1 is a subset of bitstring 2. That is, in all places bitstring 1 has a '1', bit string 2 should also have a '1'. This means that all characters in string1 are also present in string2. Can somebody please let me know the best way to do this?
  I know a simple way as follows: iterate through bit string1 and check the corresponding bit in bit string2. However, I am wondering if this can be done using some bit wise operator in a more efficient manner

Comment: How is this stored, as a `String` or as an integral value (`Integer`) occupying the first 26 bits? If the latter, simple bitwise operations ought to do the trick, else more complicated..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you really are using only 26 bits, you can use an integer (32 bits) to represent the bitset, and use the [bitwise AND](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) (&) operator, to get the [intersection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_%28set_theory%29) of the two sets.

If `a & b == a`, `a` is a subset of `b`

Answer (score 0):

If you would be using `BitSet` instead of `byte`, you could use the `and` or `xor` operators.

`BitSet` has various bit operations, except for `shift`, unfortunately.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#xor%28java.util.BitSet%29

First set `xor` second set should be 0.

Since you only use 26 characters, you can do the same with a simple `int`, too. Just setting the individual bits is a bit more messy:

```
a |= 1 << offset;
```

Comment: this checks for equality, not subset!

Comment: For subset use `a and b = a`, for equality `a xor b = 0`.